# What is the calling order when multiple methods are listening to the same INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event handler?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class Parameters (which is hooked up to INotifyPropertyChanged). Then, I have a method which listens to a property change in that class and automatically performs some calculation when a parameter changes:

```
 Parameters.PropertyChanged += Parameters_PropertyChanged;

//...

 private void Parameters_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do some calculation.
        }
```

In addition, I have another method *some place else in a different project* listening to the same thing, and displays the results:

```
 Parameters.PropertyChanged += Parameters_PropertyChanged;

//...

 private void Parameters_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Display results.
        }
```

How can I ensure that the first method is called before the second?

Comment: The ivocation order will be the same as the order in which the handlers were subscribed. But when this really matters, events are probably not the right approach. The second listener should not depend on  `//Do some calculation`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thank you, that's very useful to know.